# Passing UIViewController to another Button in another ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have three buttons like this each corresponds to a different `UIViewController`:

[image]

For example, I press button 1. It will pass to the start button the view controller corresponding to that number that it will show.

I need to be able to pass it in this button:

[image]

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just create the UIButton as property on the view controller shown on button tap.  Then, in the handler for the button tap, use the button property on the new controller to assign the button before showing the new controller.

Sample code:

```
//here's your method invoked when pressing the button 1
- (IBAction) pressedButtonOne:(id) sender {
    NewViewController *newVc = [[NewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewViewController" bundle:nil];
    newVc.startButton = self.startButton;
}
```

Here's the code in the controller created when pressing button 1

NewViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface NewViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *startButton;

//NewViewController.m
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    //use self.startButton here, for whatever you need
}
```

Comment: newVc.startButton - not found in my other VC

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly: Let's talk for button one (you can generalize it to the other buttons and VC's). Say the associated viewController is called button1ViewController.

In your button1ViewController, declare a property called button (@property(strong,non atomic) UIButton *button - also synthesize)..

In your IBAction method.

```
-(IBAction) button1Tapped:(id)sender {

button1ViewController.button = sender;

[self presentViewController:button1ViewController;

}
```

***Edit***: I think I get the question now.

In your mainView controller declare an instance variable: UIViewController *pushedController.
Also declare instances Button1ViewController *button1ViewController;
, Button2ViewController *button2ViewController, Button3ViewController *button3ViewController.

Now:

```
-(IBAction) button1Pressed:(id)sender {
     if (button1ViewController==nil) {
button1ViewController = [Button1ViewController alloc] init];
}

pushedController = button1ViewController;

}

-(IBAction) button2Pressed:(id)sender {
     if (button2ViewController==nil) {
button2ViewController = [Button2ViewController alloc] init];
}

pushedController = button2ViewController;

}


//same thing for button 3 pressed with button 3 controller


-(IBAction) startButtonPressed:(id) sender {

if (pushedViewController!=nil)
[self presentViewController:pushedViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

I think this should work, however I haven't tried the code myself.

Comment: what will I implement in the startButton?

Comment: I'm confused about the problem now, do you want to pass the view controller to the button ?

Comment: yes. the start button is in a different view controller. when button 1 is pressed, when StartButton is pressed VIEW1 will appear. But when button 2 is pressed, when StartButton is pressed VIEW2 will appear. get it now?

Comment: what is the UIViewController *pushedController? the mainView where the start is?

Comment: no pushedController is just a pointer to a UIViewController. It initially starts pointing at nothing but as you press buttons, it gets pointed to whatever view should go at the hit of the start button. So you don't have to allocate or anything just use the code above

Comment: will i declare instances in the mainView too? i only declare them in the other view.

Comment: declare all of them in the view controller that contains the 1-2-3 buttons and the start button

Comment: error "Assignment to cast is illegal, value casts are not supported

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11918/discussion-between-kobe-o4-and-kaan-dedeoglu)

Comment: I don't know how else I can help. I really tried to help you make it work